# Python Tkinter class structure practice

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
#game class
import Tkinter as tk

class Game(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):

        canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
        canvas.pack()

        button = tk.Button(canvas, text='Quit', command=self.quit_game)
        button.pack()

    def quit_game(self):
        root.destroy()#Should i put something else here?


root = tk.Tk()

game = Game(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Is it good practice, or, in other words, is there a problem with inheriting from canvas directly instead of frame, if for example I am not going to add any widgets except the canvas?

Another question I have is regarding the `root.destroy()`. I don't understand why I can't say `master.destroy()` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with inheriting from `Canvas` or any other Tkinter widget.

re `master.destroy()` vs `root.destroy()`: you can call it however you want. You simply need a reference to the root window. If you call it `root`, to destroy it you would call `root.destroy()`.

In general you should avoid the use of global variables. Given that you're passing in the root widget to your class, you can save a reference and use that instead:

```
class Game(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        ...
    def quit_game(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```